# process.getuid() not working on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a script containing only a single line of code:

```
console.log('userid: ' + process.getuid());
```

When I run the script using the command `node filename.js`, following error occurs:

```
node.js:201
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick  
^  
TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'getuid'  
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\PROGRA~1\nodejs\node_modules\mrt\p.js:1:96)  
at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)  
at Object..js (module.js:459:10)  
at Module.load (module.js:348:31)  
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)  
at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)  
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I am running node.js on Windows.

Comment: That single line of code should run fine by itself.  What version are you using?

Comment: I have downloaded last version; v0.6.15

Comment: I rechecked everything but the error exists. Is it a bug in node?!

Comment: Are you using Node.js on Windows?

Comment: yes I'm using Node on Windows 7

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I rephrased it a bit to be more specific. Node.js Does not have all the same functions on Windows as on Posix systems.

Comment: If you are running program on IE then It will not work, because console.log is not working in IE

Comment: https://github.com/sourcemint/sm-npm/issues/6 seem to be a known bug on windows @AKA if he tries to run node.js scripts in the browser he's doing it wrong

Answer (score 11):

Old question I know but thought I would tidy this up incase anyone else is searching.

Just checking through [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getuid) it would seem that:

> Note: this function is only available on POSIX platforms (i.e. not Windows)

Cheers

John

Answer (score 1):

Since I had problems to update npm@2.12.0, here the commands that let me solve the issue:

```
npm uninstall -g npm
npm install -g npm@2.12.1
```

To check your your version afterwards:

```
npm -v
```

Should be 2.12.1 then. After that I could run my install/update commands normally.

Source: See [Idez](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8737#issuecomment-116274426) comment under github.